# Conditional formatting of entire table in FlexTable

Tags: r, flextable

What I want to do is conditionally format an entire table in r based on a value, I am currently trying this with flextable:

```
#some data 
SalesData<-data.frame(Appliance=c("Radio", "Laptop", "TV", "Fridge"), ThisYear=c(5,25,5,8), LastYear=c(6,20,5,8))

#use flextable to conditionally format the data so that anything in the ThisYear column more than 10 is light blue
library(flextable)

SalesData<-regulartable(SalesData)
SalesData<-bg(SalesData, i = ~ ThisYear >10,j= ~ ThisYear,bg = "light blue")
SalesData
```

The tables I have can be quite large so how can I apply this to the whole table without have to specify the formatting for each individual column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought I would post the final code here as it may help someone:
The code loops around the columns specified in the 'columns' vector and colorises them according to its values.

```
#some data 
SalesData<-data.frame(Appliance=c("Radio", "Laptop", "TV", "Fridge"), ThisYear=c(5,11,5,12), LastYear=c(19,20,5,8))

library(flextable)
SalesData<-regulartable(SalesData)

#list of columns to loop through
columns<-c("ThisYear","LastYear")

#loop to colorise the columns
for (i in seq_along(columns)){
#anything with a value of more than 10 is formatted light blue
eval(parse(text= paste0("SalesData<-", "bg (SalesData,i=~", columns[i], ">10, j=~", columns[i], " ,bg=\"light blue\")")))
}
#show the table
SalesData
```

Comment: how do I  modify this if I am comparing character values, e.g. instead of static value like 10, I am comparing every cell value columnwise to a ref column cell value.

Comment: Change the static number to the name of your reference column. For example:   eval(parse(text= paste0("SalesData<-", "bg (SalesData,i=~", columns[i], ">ReferenceCol, j=~", columns[i], " ,bg=\"light blue\")")))

Answer (score 4):

Please check also the [examples](https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/reference/bg.html) of the `bg` function.

As of `flextable V0.6.5`, conditional formatting can be achieved rather easily using color mapping, e.g. `scales::col_*` [functions](https://scales.r-lib.org/reference/col_numeric.html).

Here another possible solution for the previous example:

```r
library(flextable)

# Some data 
SalesData <- data.frame(Appliance = c("Radio", "Laptop", "TV", "Fridge"), 
                        ThisYear = c(5, 11, 5, 12), 
                        LastYear = c(19, 20, 5, 8))

# List of columns to loop through
columns <- c("ThisYear","LastYear")

# Define colors and ranges
bg_picker <- scales::col_bin(
    palette = c("white", "light blue"),
    domain = c(0, 100), # min and max range can be also set dynamically 
    bins = c(0, 10, 20)) # as well as the bins


ftab <- regulartable(SalesData) %>% 
    bg(j = columns, bg = bg_picker)

# Show the table
ftab
```

[image]

Comment: I find this to be the best, and most useful answer on the thread. the `scales::col_*` functions are easier than the accepted solution below and have implementations for factors and other data types.

Answer (score 3):

To do that you can either not use `j`, or set its value to column names:

```
SalesData<-data.frame(Appliance=c("Radio", "Laptop", "TV", "Fridge"), ThisYear=c(5,25,5,8), LastYear=c(6,20,5,8))

# option 1
ft1 <-regulartable(SalesData)
ft1 <-bg(ft1, i = ~ ThisYear >10, bg = "light blue")
ft1

# option 2 (recommanded)
ft2 <-regulartable(SalesData)
ft2 <- bg(ft, i = ~ ThisYear >10, j = names(SalesData), bg = "light blue")
ft2
```

[image]

Comment: To clarify my question, the effect I was after was to apply the formatting of >10 giving a light blue cell to each cell in the table. So to do it manually in this example would be to add   SalesData<-bg(SalesData, i = ~ LastYear >10,j= ~ LastYear,bg = "light blue") to the code

Comment: (So if I understand, this would not work with `Appliance`...) You will then need to iterate over columns you want to colorize...